# Play Framework 2.2.2 with JDK 1.7.0_79 Starting issue

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using Fedora , Play 2.2.2 and JDK 1.7.0_79

I have Created new project HelloWorld, when i try to run it , getting the 
following error

> [HelloWorld] $ run
>
> --- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
>
> [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
>
> (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
>
> [info] play - Application started (Dev) [error] application -
>
> ! Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/Application :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_79]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_79]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_79]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>   [error] application - Error while rendering default error page
>   scala.MatchError: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   controllers/Application : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (of
>   class java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError)     at
>   play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:131)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]    at
>   play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:189)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]     at
>   play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:73)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]     at
>   play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:83)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]     at
>   play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:81)
>   [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]     at
>   scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
>   [scala-library.jar:na]

I am new to play and don't getting any idea... followed pdf tutorial  and downloaded the same version of play 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say exactly, but this is typically because you `run` with `jdk 1.7` and compile with `jdk 1.8`. You can try adding the following to your build.sbt:

`javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")`

You definitely only have `jdk 1.7` installed?

Comment: Thanks @ed. This worked for me.  i have only jdk 1.7 in my machine, jdk 1.8 is not present in the machine.